# NW.js trouble exporting modules

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nwjs, module.exports

I am trying to use `module.exports()` to create a new module in my NW.js application.

I have two files that I am using:

*Index.js*

```js
const gkm = require('gkm'); //This is a key listener
const AudioStreamMeter = require('audio-stream-meter'); //This is a mic listener
const exportable = require("./twitchAuth.js");

exportable.test();
// More code under this
```

*twitchAuth.js*

```js
function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById("volume").style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
}

module.exports(doSomething);
```

only thing is that when I add `const exportable = require("./separateFile.js");` to `index.js` then `gkm` and `audio-stream-meter` stop working as well as the rest of my code.

[View the full source code here](https://github.com/bomeers/Bird-Brain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a PR to fix a bunch of stuff in the repo:

- https://github.com/bomeers/Bird-Brain/pull/1

the main issue here though is that `module.exports` is not a function, it would be assigned an object, such as:

```js
module.exports = { doSomething };
```

And your paths for importing aren't relative to the CWD

```js
const exportable = require("../app/twitchAuth.js");
```